# Работа с динамическими массивами в языке Си.

Tags: c

Подскажите,пожалуйста, где ошибка

Задание: Ввести массив строк, число которых заранее неизвестно. признаком конца ввода строки является ввод указанной последовательности символов. Признаком конца ввода массива является ввод строки, содержащей не менее указанного количества гласных букв. Вывести массив на экран

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
    char** arr;
    char* a;
    char vowel[13], b;
    int sizex = 1, sizey = 1, size, n, i = 0, j = 0, cnt = 0, m, z, y;
    arr = (char**)malloc(sizey*sizeof(char*));
    arr[i] = (char*)malloc(sizex*sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter size of a sequence: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    a = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    for (n = 0; n<size; n++)
    {
        printf("Enter a sequence: ");
        scanf("%c", &a[n]);
    }
    vowel[13] = "aeiouyAEIOUY";
    printf("Declare the number of vowels: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    for (i = 0, sizey = 1;;)
    {
        arr = (char**)realloc(arr, sizey*sizeof(char*));
        for (j = 0, sizex = 1;;)
        {
            arr[i] = (char*)realloc(arr[i], sizex*sizeof(char));
            scanf("%c", &arr[i][j]);
            for (z = 0;z<12;z++) 
                if (arr[i][j] == vowel[z]) cnt++;// считаем количество гласных
            y = j;
            if (size <= sizex)// прекращение ввода строки
            {
                for (n = size - 1; n != -1, arr[i][j] == a[n]; j--, n--);
                if (n == -1) break;
                else {
                    j = y + 1;
                    sizex++;
                    }
            }
        }
        if (cnt >= m) break;
        else {
            i++;
            sizey++;
            }
    }
    for (i = 0; i<sizey; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<sizex; j++)
            printf("%c", &arr[i][j]);
    for (i = 0; i < sizey; i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);
    printf("\n\t Press any key");
    scanf("%c", b);
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@KSENIYA](/users/19132/kseniya)](/users/19132/kseniya), было бы хорошо, если бы Вы прямо указали, что Вы наблюдаете и распознаете как ошибку.

--

Видимо, одной из целей данного задания является реализация некой модификации (в виде определения многосимвольного конца строки) известной функции GNU `getline()` (можете почитать `man` на нее).

Рекомендую начать именно с нее. Потом, используя ее же для чтения последовательности символов (у Вас переменная `a`) и освоенную технику программирования расширения динамического массива (строка ведь, это тот же массив), Вы легко запрограммируете расширение массива строк.

--

Так что -- `man getline`.